# How to pass function reference into arguments

Tags: c++, function, boost, reference

I'm using boost::function for making function-references:

```
typedef boost::function<void (SomeClass &handle)> Ref;
someFunc(Ref &pointer) {/*...*/}

void Foo(SomeClass &handle) {/*...*/}
```

What is the best way to pass **Foo** into the **someFunc**?
I tried something like:

```
someFunc(Ref(Foo));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to pass a temporary object to the function, it must take the argument either by value or by constant reference. Non-constant references to temporary objects aren't allowed. So either of the following should work:

```
void someFunc(const Ref&);
someFunc(Ref(Foo)); // OK, constant reference to temporary

void someFunc(Ref);
someFunc(Ref(Foo)); // OK, copy of temporary

void someFunc(Ref&);
someFunc(Ref(Foo)); // Invalid, non-constant reference to temporary
Ref ref(Foo);
someFunc(ref); // OK, non-constant reference to named object
```

By the way, calling the type `Ref` and the instance `pointer` when it's neither a reference nor a pointer could be a bit confusing.